# SQL storing and retrieving carriage return

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm facing problems retrieving carriage returns from text stored in my database.

I have something like

```
Hello World! My name is Gunter*.

*Sometimes also known as Mueller.
```

stored in MySQL database. When I check on the data via phpMyAdmin, the text looks fine with the carriage return.

However, when I retrieve it using mysqli in PHP to be delivered to a webpage, it returns as

```
Hello World! My name is Gunter*. *Sometimes also known as Mueller.
```

How do I maintain the carriage return in my output?

Comment: It's very unlikely that MySQL is removing a carriage return character from values being returned. I suspect this has nothing to do with MySQL. I recommend you do a "view page source" in your browser. To get output to show a "carriage return" in the browser, the browser needs appropriate markup, e.g. "`Dear John,<p>I just got back...`" or "`<br>item1<br>item2<br>item3`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carriage return doesn't affect rendered HTML.  View source to see if its there.  But for rendered HTML you're going to have to string replace carriage return to `<br/>`.  For that you can use like:

```
echo nl2br($stringWithCarriageReturnInIt);
```

This function actually keeps the newline character and adds `<br/>` in front of it. So you will see the newline now in your rendered HTML, and also in view source.